# javascript ignore my IF Statements whan useing while Statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

so i got an exercises in javascript
and now some PHP but it was long ago and i start to come back to code.
i taking a course on web development and i need to PRINT ALL NUMBERS DIVISIBLE BY 5 AND 3 BETWEEN 5 AND 50.
so its not working out so much and the com ignoring my if and else statement.
i want to understand why its happening.
tnx for everyone

```
console.log("PRINT ALL NUMBERS DIVISIBLE BY 5 AND 3 BETWEEN 5 AND 50");
var num = 0 ;
if(num = 0){
  num++;
  console.log(num + " first if");
}
else if (!(num % 3 === 0 && num % 5 === 0)){
  num ++;
console.log(num + " second if");
}
else {
  while(num <= 50){
  console.log(num);
  num++;
}
}
```

Comment: `if(num = 0)` - `=` means *assignment*. For an equality check use `==` or `===`.

Comment: Also: any checks you do for being divisible by 3 and 5 need to be inside the loop. Furthermore: with `(num % 3 === 0 && num % 5 === 0)`, you're checking if a number is divisible by 15. I'm guessing that was not the point of the exercise.

Comment: tnx guys its helped

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have your loops in the wrong configuration, put your if statements inside the whole loop...

```
var num = 0;
while(num <= 50) {
    if (num == 0) {
        console.log(num + " is zero");
    } else if (num % 3 === 0 && num % 5 === 0) {
        console.log(num + " divisible by 3 and 5");
    } else {
        console.log(num);
    }
    num++;
}
```

Comment: i will put the first if out side of the loop couse its going only for one num but you helped me alot. tnx